# Resetting Root password mount is already mounted or busy

Tags: rhel-7

The real issue I cannot understand.

VMWare 6.7

Red Hat 7

```
uname -a
Linux servername.net 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 26 15:05:43 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Selinux Enforcing

1. From the VMWARE web console I cannot log in as any user.
2. When I ssh, I cannot log in as root because root login is disabled, however there are other user on the system

ie. user1, I know the password and is in the sudoers file

```
cat /etc/sudoers | grep user1
user1    ALL=(ALL)     ALL
```

I can ssh in as user1, however when I try to sudo i get "Sorry, try again."

What could be preventing either of these?

1. Not able to log in as root or any other user on the console
2. user not being able to sudo

So now I have moved on the trying to edit the os files in edit mode.

Following this article:

https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-reset-root-user-password-in-centos-rhel-7/

I reboot the system

As soon as I hit e and add the rd.break to the end of the line

After hitting Ctrl-x

I get prompted for a password.

I enter the root user and the root password, and it works, lets me in

How?

get to the "switch_root" prompt

```
mount -o remount.rw /sysroot

mount: /dev/mapper/rhel-root is already mounted or /sysroot busy
       /dev/mapper/rhel-root is already mounted on /sysroot
```

How can i get the system in read write to be able to edit, or change the root password?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not entered the correct syntax :

```
mount -o remount,rw /sysroot
```

A comma **,** should be used instead of a dot **.**